# I can't set image ad fatured programatically

Tags: php, uploads, post-thumbnails

I have a problem when I try to set image as featured. I don't know where is the fail, I upload the image from a URL in the same server and then try to set it as featured. The code upload the image but don't set it as featured. The code I used is:

```
$fotoid = media_sideload_image( $imagesres."/".$row->foto1, $restaurantid, '' );
$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment($fotoid, $row->foto1, $restaurantid);
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $row->foto1 );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
set_post_thumbnail($restaurantid, $attach_id);
```

Where `$restauranid` is the ID of the post. `$imageres` is the url of the image, and `$row->foto1` is image title and extension.

Thanks!

Comment: if it doesn't do what you expect it to, what happens instead? Does the sideloaded image appear in the media library? Where do `$row` and `$imagesres` come from? I notice none of your function calls are checked if they return error messages and it's assumed they always work, e.g. if `media_sideload_image` fails it will return a `WP_Error` object instead of an ID that contains an explanation of what happened but there are no checks for this in the code

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i managed to resolve the issue by using this code.

```
//insert featured image
function Generate_Featured_Image( $featured_image, $product_id  ){

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($featured_image);
    //$filename = basename($featured_image);
    $filename = basename($image_url, '.jpg') . (string) rand(0, 5000) . '.jpg';
    if(wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else                                    $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $product_id );
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1= wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2= set_post_thumbnail( $product_id, $attach_id );
}
Generate_Featured_Image( $featured_image,   $product_id );
```

what you have to do is to pass parameters upon calling functions.
Code goes to your theme or child-theme's functions.php file.